# Handling with events mouseDown and mouseUp in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, events, mousedown, mouseup

I want to create an application with this functionality, it's simple:
When click down the mouse a button I want to change the text of a label and when I click up to change again this label text.

Can you help me, please? Dont know how to do

I did this:

```
#import "MyButton.h"

@implementation MyButton

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"down");
}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"up");  
}
```

and it works, but when I want to handle the events, nothing happens

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your `NSTextField` hooked up to an `IBOutlet` named `label`:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
     [label setStringValue:@"hi"];
}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event
{
     [label setStringValue:@"bye"];
}
```

Comment: Where should I do this?
I've tried but it doesn't work.

I might explain bad what I want to do:
I want to press a button (click down) and capture that event, showing a message in a label for example.
And when I unpress the button (click up), capture that event to. Showing another message

Comment: In your `NSButton` subclass as you have set up.

Comment: And how do I link/connect that label (which is in MainMenu.xib) to my subclass?